# How can I shift signal in time in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a signal `x(t)`. I must shift it `a/2` and `-a/2` and then take the sum of these two shifted signals. How can I write shift of `x(t)` in time in C++?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: Your question reminded me of [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.object/k4T2x50lPPM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For time series data a shift in time is just an offset of n samples, so to sum data which is shifted by +/-a/2 samples:

```
for (i = a/2; i < N - a/2; ++i)
{
    y[i] = x[i - a/2] + x[i + a/2];
}
```